# Get mobile number from facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have added the extended property sms to my required permissions.

In my case im using the .net facebook sdk but I dont think it matters.

I don't know where to find the users phone number

```
  var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
  dynamic me = fb.Get("me");
```

I have had a look within "me" however there is nothing there for me to get the mobile number.

Can someone point me in the right direction where I can find the users mobile number?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the FB Graph API to retrieve a user's mobile phone?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3698558/how-do-i-use-the-fb-graph-api-to-retrieve-a-users-mobile-phone)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facebook has retracted these features of the API due to privacy concerns.

Source: [Here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/jan/18/facebook-privacy-data)